# As I'm building my first site with CodeIgniter, what resources should I have handy?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm building an organization's website, that is a mixture of static and dynamic content with a bit of functionality (login, search and results, a few forms etc)

Usually I build from scratch using MySQL and PHP but I'm interested in using CodeIgniter.

Obviously the official user guide is a good place to start - Any other suggestions?

I want to make sure that I'm building it in an elegant, secure and best-practice sort of way. Though I also don't want to complicate things and bite off more than I can chew just yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a useful kick-starter tutorial on CodeIgnitor:

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want to use [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/)? Then you'd have lots of CI source code to look at that created in a best-practices kind of way. Search, forms, login (member management) are already built...

For learning CI:

- cheat sheet:
  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/quick_reference.html
- http://codeigniter-resources.com/categories/tutorials
- http://theyoboo.blogspot.com/2010/05/codeigniter-resourceschecklist-thingy.html